# What does the Torah think of Pangea?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, rabbis, science, creation

What does Torah literature say about [Pangaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangaea)?

Is it considered be legitimate? Are there sources which lean either way?

Comment: Do you mean "assuming the world is old enough to have had a pangea"? And if so why would you think not? Though I'm not sure what " a legitimate occurrence" even means.

Comment: According to the continental drift theory, Pangea was not the first super continent, nor will it have been the last, so it's not so significant in it's own right. (Somewhat interesting is that Pangea is kind of shaped like a fetus, and Israel is kind of where the belly button would be. Kind of)

Answer (score 3):

A very interesting source is found in the discussion of the splitting of the earth in the times of Peleg.

[Rav Moshe Yitzchak Ashkenazi](http://alhatorah.org/Commentators:R.%20Moshe%20Yitzchak%20Ashkenazi%20(Hoil%20Moshe)) quotes Rav Yitzchak Chaim (Vittorio) Castiglioni ([Italian bio](http://www.rabbini.it/vittorio-castiglioni/)), who supports the interpretation that prior to the Dor Haflaga, we all lived together on Pangaea, and that is when the splitting of the continents took place:

> ומהח״ר יח״ק הואיל לקיים סברת האומר שחלקי הארץ הזאת התפרדו איש מעל אחיו (אמיריקא מאיורופא ואפריקא, ואוסטרליאה ואיי הים סביבותיה מאסיא) מחמת הפיכת המבול, וזה היה כמו מאה שנה אחר המבול עצמו בימי הולדת פלג ומזה שמו.‏

Comment: Although I enjoy these types of ideas very much, this is pseudo science at best. When would they say the continents drifted and or the flood happened?

Comment: @user6591 My guess is that according to them, this would work as some sort of miracle taking place following the flood a few thousand years ago, and might work in conjunction with the story of G-d spreading out the nations on the face of the earth following the building of the Tower of Babel.

Comment: These rabbis did live before carbon dating and other more modern tools used in dating the earth and the universe existed. I wonder what many of the rabbis who embraced the late 19th century science would say to today's version. On that list of course would be of rabbi Hirsch and the Tiferes Yisroel amongst many others.